# Why is ternary search used to find the max/min of an unimodal function?

Tags: algorithm, search, binary, ternary-search

I have learned that finding the minimum/maximum of an unimodal function can be done with [ternary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search#:%7E:text=A%20ternary%20search%20determines%20either,algorithm%20(see%20search%20algorithm)), an algorithm that runs in `O(logN)` time (where `N` is the size of the given search range).

However, I recently had the thought that maybe we could accomplish finding the max/min of an unimodal function with binary search as well. Specifically, for functions that have a definite maximum, we could find and return the first x-value for which `f(x) >= f(x+Epsilon)` (where Epsilon is the allowed error bound). On the other hand, for functions that have a definite minimum, we could find and return the first x-value such that `f(x) <= f(x+Epsilon)`.

Overall, my question is, why is ternary search used at all for this search operation if binary search can accomplish the same applications? Am I missing something here, or have I made some other logical mistake?

Answer (score 0):

There are some scenarios where binary search wont be helpful but ternary search can yield desired results.

Here is a [resource](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-advantage-of-a-ternary-search-over-a-binary-search) that helps you understand in detail about it.

Answer (score 0):

Let [`f(x) = -x^2 + 3`](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/53818?#comment-378364). Let `Epsilon = 2`.

The first `x`-value for which `f(x) >= f(x+Epsilon)` is -1:

```
f(-1) = 2 = f(-1 + 2) = f(1) = 2
```

But the answer is `x = 0`.

Comment: If `Epsilon` is the allowed error bound though, wouldn't the answer of `-1` would be acceptable in this context because it is less than 2 away from the true correct answer, which is `0`?

Comment: @Telescope OP stated in the question description: "we could accomplish finding the max/min of an unimodal function with binary search." What you are suggesting is not "the max/min."